# Plot loss and accuracy over each epoch for both training and test datasets

Tags: python, keras, pytorch, cross-validation, loss

I am training that model to classify 3 classes (0,1,2). I am using cross validation for 2 fold, I am using pytorch, I would like to plot the accuracy and loss function for training and test dataset over the number epochs on the same plot. I do know how to do that . especially I just evaluate the test once I finish training , Is there is way that I can have that plot for both training  data and test data

```
# Configuration options
k_folds = 2
loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
# For fold results
results = {}
# Set fixed random number seed
torch.manual_seed(42)
# Prepare dataset by concatenating Train/Test part; we split later.
training_set = CustomDataset('one_hot_train_data.txt','train_3states_target.txt') #training_set = CustomDataset_3('one_hot_train_data.txt','train_5_target.txt')
training_generator = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(training_set, **params)
val_set = CustomDataset('one_hot_val_data.txt','val_3states_target.txt')
test_set = CustomDataset('one_hot_test_data.txt','test_3states_target.txt')
#testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_set, **params)
#dataset1 = ConcatDataset([training_set, val_set])
dataset = ConcatDataset([training_set,test_set])
kfold = KFold(n_splits=k_folds, shuffle=True)

# Start print
print('--------------------------------')
# K-fold Cross Validation model evaluation
for fold, (train_ids, test_ids) in enumerate(kfold.split(dataset)):
    # Print
    print(f'FOLD {fold}')
    print('--------------------------------')
    # Sample elements randomly from a given list of ids, no replacement.
    train_subsampler = torch.utils.data.SubsetRandomSampler(train_ids)
    test_subsampler = torch.utils.data.SubsetRandomSampler(test_ids)

    # Define data loaders for training and testing data in this fold
    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset,**params, sampler=train_subsampler)
    testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
       dataset,
       **params, sampler=test_subsampler)
    # Init the neural network
    model = PPS()
    model.to(device)
    # Initialize optimizer
    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)
    # Run the training loop for defined number of epochs
    train_acc = []
    for epoch in range(0, N_EPOCHES):
        # Print epoch
        print(f'Starting epoch {epoch + 1}')
        # Set current loss value
        running_loss = 0.0
        epoch_loss = 0.0
        a = []
        # Iterate over the DataLoader for training data
        for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
            inputs, targets = data
            inputs = inputs.unsqueeze(-1)
            #inputs = inputs.to(device)
            targets = targets.to(device)
            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            # print(inputs.shape,targets.shape)
            # Zero the gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            # Perform forward pass
            loss,outputs = model(inputs,targets)
            outputs = outputs.to(device)

            # Perform backward pass
            loss.backward()
            # Perform optimization
            optimizer.step()
            # print statistics
            running_loss += loss.item()
            epoch_loss += loss
            a.append(torch.sum(outputs == targets))
            # print(outputs.shape,outputs.shape[0])

            if i % 2000 == 1999:  # print every 2000 mini-batches
                print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                      (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000), "acc",
                      torch.sum(outputs == targets) / float(outputs.shape[0]))
                running_loss = 0.0
            # sum_acc += (outputs == stat_batch.argmax(1)).float().sum()
        print("epoch", epoch + 1, "acc", sum(a) / len(train_subsampler), "loss", epoch_loss / len(trainloader))
        train_acc.append(sum(a) / len(train_subsampler))
    state = {'epoch': epoch + 1, 'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
                     'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict() }
    torch.save(state, path + name_file + "model_epoch_i_" + str(epoch) + str(fold)+".cnn")
    #torch.save(model.state_dict(), path + name_file + "model_epoch_i_" + str(epoch) + ".cnn")
    # Print about testing
    print('Starting testing')

# Evaluation for this fold  
    correct, total = 0, 0
    with torch.no_grad():
    # Iterate over the test data and generate predictions
     for i, data in enumerate(testloader, 0):
        # Get inputs
        inputs, targets = data
        #targets = targets.to(device)
        inputs = inputs.unsqueeze(-1)
        inputs = inputs.to(device)
        # Generate outputs
        loss,outputs = model(inputs,targets)
        outputs.to(device)
        print("out",outputs.shape)
        print("target",targets.shape)
        print("targetsize",targets.size(0))
        print("sum",(outputs == targets).sum().item())
        #print("sum",torch.sum(outputs == targets))

        # Set total and correct
       # _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        total += targets.size(0)
        correct += (outputs == targets).sum().item()
        #correct += torch.sum(outputs == targets)

    
    # Print accuracy
    print('Accuracy for fold %d: %d %%' % (fold,float( 100.0 * float(correct / total))))
    print('--------------------------------')
    results[fold] = 100.0 * float(correct / total)

# Print fold results
print(f'K-FOLD CROSS VALIDATION RESULTS FOR {k_folds} FOLDS')
print('--------------------------------')
sum = 0.0
for key, value in results.items():
    print(f'Fold {key}: {value} %')
    sum += value
print(f'Average: {float(sum / len(results.items()))} %')
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use Tensorboard that is built especially for that, here is the doc for pytorch : https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html

So in your case when you are printing the result, you can just do a

```py
writer.add_scalar('accuracy/train',  torch.sum(outputs == targets) / float(outputs.shape[0]), n_iter)
```

EDIT : adding small example that you can follow

Let's say that you are training a model :

```py
model_name = 'network'
log_name = '{}_{}'.format(model_name, strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'))
writer = SummaryWriter('logs/{}'.format(log_name))

net = Model()
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.1)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    losses = []
    for i, (inputs,labels) in enumerate (trainloader):
        inputs = Variable(inputs.float())
        labels = Variable(labels.float())
        outputs = net(inputs)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        losses.append(loss)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        correct_values += (outputs == labels).float().sum()
    accuracy = 100 * correct_values / len(training_set)
    avg_loss = sum(losses) / len(training_set)
    writer.add_scalar('loss/train', avg_loss.item(), epoch)
    writer.add_scalar('acc/train', accuracy, epoch)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply , could you please tell me where i put it since i print every 2000 batch, but i want to plot over each epoch , Also for testing where no epochs there, i understood the documentation but I am not able to apply it in my example.

Comment: I edited my answer, you should see then where you can put it, for the testing you are doing only one epoch so you can do the same thing but just show the final value with a `writer.add_scalar('acc/test', accuracy, 1)`, alternatively you can use a validation set that you will only use time to time and plot on those data how the network reacts.

Comment: In my code , I combine  training and test data set to do k fold cross validation . In my code also there are validation data set I did not use . Could you please let me know how I can use it to have another plot during testing

Comment: In my code , I combine training and test data set to do k fold cross validation . In my code also there are validation data set I did not use . Could you please let me know how I can use it to have another plot during validating?

Comment: The good thing with pytorch and tensorboard is that you can do whatever you want, you could check if epoch is modulo validation_frequency (`if epoch % val_frequency == 0`) and then iterate over your data and do the same thing as train but with putting a net.train(False) and ending with  `writer.add_scalar('loss/val', avg_loss.item(), epoch)
    writer.add_scalar('acc/val', accuracy, epoch)`

Comment: @OrpheeFaucoz May I kindly draw your attention to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71305465/how-can-plot-loss-curves-for-training-and-test-for-multi-output-regression-task).